# How to pass parametrs to scheduled apex class?

Tags: salesforce, apex, schedule

I have a method where I need to schedule an apex class that will close several Cases in 5 days but I need to somehow pass Case Id so the scheduled class knows which cases to remove after 5 days. How to do it?

Now schedule method looks like this but CloseInactiveCaseSchedulable is empty

```
public static void scheduleCloseCaseJob(List<Case> cases, Map<Id, Case> oldCases) {
    for (Case c : cases) {
        if (c.Status == 'Waiting for customer reply' || c.Status == 'Waiting for customer approval') {
            String day = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().addDays(20).day());
            String hour = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().hour());
            String min = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().minute()); 
            String ss = String.valueOf(Datetime.now().second());

            //parse to cron expression
            String nextFireTime = ss + ' ' + min + ' ' + hour + ' ' + day +' * ?';
            System.schedule('Close Inactive Case in 20 days with Id ' + c.Id, nextFireTime, new CloseInactiveCaseSchedulable());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't have to be like that:

```
System.schedule('Close Inactive Case in 20 days with Id ' + c.Id, nextFireTime, new CloseInactiveCaseSchedulable());
```

You can pass any parameters you want, to constructor

```
Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>{'005....', '005...'};
System.schedule('Close Inactive Case in 20 days with Id ' + c.Id, 
    nextFireTime, 
    new CloseInactiveCaseSchedulable(ids)
);
```

Or have a parameterless constructor and pass it after

```
CloseInactiveCaseSchedulable job = new CloseInactiveCaseSchedulable();
job.ids = new Set<Id>{'005....', '005...'};
System.schedule('Close Inactive Case in 20 days with Id ' + c.Id, 
    nextFireTime, 
    job
);
```

The Schedulable interface enforces on you only the existence of the `execute` method. Your class can have no constructor, constructor without params or with params, whatever you need.

(Don't schedule them in a loop though. Collect the IDs in the loop and then have 1 `System.schedule()` call outside of it).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use it by passing parameters through the constructor and storing them in instance variables -

```
public class CloseInactiveCaseSchedulable implements Schedulable{

    public Set<Id> caseIds;

    public void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        scheduleClassMethod(caseIds);
    }

    public void scheduleClassMethod(Set<Id> setcaseIds){
      //your logic
    }

    public CloseInactiveCaseSchedulable ( Set<Id> setcaseIds) {
        if ( !setcaseIds.isEmpty() ) {
            caseIds = setcaseIds;
        }
    }

}
```

and then you can use the below scenario to pass parameters in **System.schedule**

```
        System.schedule('Close Inactive Case in 20 days with Id ' + c.Id, nextFireTime, CloseInactiveCaseSchedulable(new String[]{'500xxx','b500xx}));
```

Let me know, it help you out.

Thanks.